# Simplify How to Call the Function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, if-statement

I have code to replace a word if that word contained in the array. The code its work but there is problem first it's too long and I can't repeat the code(call the result two or more time in page). I want to simplify how to call the function and can repeat to call the result. Here is my code :

```
$str = 'APPLE';
$fruits = array('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'AVOCADO');
$string = $str;
foreach ($fruits as $url) {
    if (strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE) {
        echo "FRUIT";
        return true;
    }
}

echo $string;return false;
```

For that code, I want to call the result just using `$group`. Thank all...

Comment: you should look into `in_array()`..

Comment: Then preg_grep instead of in_array. But there may be other code in the loop we don't know about. And in all fairness a loop is needed either way.

Comment: @NigelRen which, to me, implies a potential lack of PHP knowledge, using `strpos()` to see if a string is contained within a looped array.. just doesn't seem like contained is the word OP wants. Maybe a comment to OP to get clarity, e.g. will/should APPLE pass for APPLE PIE for instance.. which, as sucky as it is, is not a fruit

Comment: Hi thank you for comment.., yeah, I still a newbie and of course lack of PHP knowledge... hehehe For my case `$str` is one world, so it must be APPLE, not APPLE PIE and yeah I want an exact match...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my answer, based on last OP comment:

> Hi thank you for comment.., yeah, I still a newbie and of course lack of PHP knowledge... hehehe For my case $str is one world, so it must be APPLE, not APPLE PIE and yeah I want an exact match...

If you have your array of fruits and know the needle, then all you need to really do is `in_array()`:

```
function checkFruit($search)
{
    $fruits = ['APPLE', 'BANANA', 'AVOCADO'];
    return (in_array($search, $fruits) ? 'FRUIT' : $search);
}

$str = 'APPLE';
echo 'An apple is a '. checkFruit($str);

$str = 'COW';
echo 'A cow is a '. checkFruit($str);
```

All we're doing is checking if the passed string is in the array of $fruits, if it is return 'FRUIT'. You could return a bool type, but unless you're doing further checks along the way, seems a bit pointless when you're wanting FRUIT.

[see it in action](https://phpfiddle.tk/565a692d)

Comment: Hi.., I've been trying your code but when the `$str` is not between `'APPLE', 'BANANA', 'AVOCADO'` for example, if `$str` is `COW` the result is blank not `COW`

Comment: @benkmad if it's exact match you want then this is the answer you should use. The other answer does not require exact match.

Answer (score 2):

**First thing**

You've defined `$str` as 'APPLE' and then defined `$string` as `$str`, why not just define `$string` directly as 'APPLE'.

**Second thing**

You'll want to make use of functions, storing the code as a function means you can call it again without having to re-write all of the code out, please see below for an example:

```
function FindFruit($find, $haystack) {

    foreach($haystack as $k => $v) {

        $result = (strpos($v, $find) !== false ? true : false);

        if($result == true) return 'FRUIT';

    }

    return $find;

}

$fruits = array('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'AVOCADO');
$string = 'APPLE';

$result = FindFruit($string, $fruits);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer.., First, I define the $str as `APPLE` because it's connected to another code. Second i've been try your code but the result is `FRUITAPPLEAPPLE` not `FRUIT` and i can't call `echo $result;` two time or more.. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it will only output either 'FRUIT' or 'APPLE' depending on whether or not it was found or not. In response to your second point, can you elaborate what you mean by "I can't call `echo result` two time or more".

Comment: I've been trying your code again and the result is `FRUIT1` not `FRUIT` and when I call for two times the result is `FRUIT11` not `FRUIT1FRUIT1`. 
For "I can't call echo result two times or more", I mean is a repetition to call `$result`.

Comment: Can you describe in as much detail as possible in your question what your desired output is.

Comment: Okay,  when `$str` is `APPLE` and `APPLE` contained on
`array('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'AVOCADO')` the result is `FRUIT` but if  `$str` is `COW` that mean not in array the result is `COW`. And when I call `echo $result;' will show `FRUIT` but when call `echo $result; echo $result;' will show `FRUITFRUIT`

Comment: I've just updated my answer - please give this a try.